# Vanishing drop down menu issue in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, drop-down-menu

The following gif demonstrates my issue:

[image]

You open the drop down menu, you try to scroll, the drop down menu disappears (does not close, but just... vanishes). If you wait a few seconds, it comes back and now works perfectly fine.

I have only been able to see this issue on iOS devices. The gif recording was on iPhone XS simulator in safari on iOS 12.

Has anyone encountered such an issue and might know a fix? I have tried to increase the z-index, I have tried to add the `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` hack that is demonstrated [in this article](https://muffinman.io/ios-safari-scroll-position-fixed/), but neither of which produced any luck.

I am wondering if anyone may know better than I what could be happening here and how it could potentially be fixed. The real kicker is this only seems to happen on the Salesforce 1 app on iOS devices, so not sure how easy it will be to reproduce this in a general context... But hoping someone has an idea to prevent it from doing this.

General browsers and Android seem just fine, this only came up with iOS.

I also couldn't notice anything odd happening in the CSS when inspecting the drop down when it was disappearing, then if I modified in the CSS in the dev tools, it all the sudden rendered and worked fine. This is starting to look like some iOS rendering issue that is seeming beyond my control as I have been unable to find any CSS that stops this...

Comment: It does sound like an iOS rendering bug, a class of bugs which can be very hard to diagnose and fix. You could try giving the element an opacity of 0.99, which has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not end up working for me. My hope is that someone has encountered something similar and has some CSS tricks or something to try that will end up working lol. My fear is that those might work in just a browser, but in the Salesforce app Salesforce does some junk that renders it useless...

Comment: Yeah I assume the app uses an embedded browser (some WebKit version probably) but it might not have been updated in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found something that kind of works for this kind of issue.

In each of the 'open' events for my multiselects and drop down kendo widgets, I attached a 'scroll' event to the `k-list-scroller` element of the drop down/multiselect. The scroll event would then increment the z-index on each trigger of the scroll. This forced a rerender of the drop down element and it no longer disappeared.

There is a slight split second twitch to the drop down as it quickly disappears and reappears due to the z-index changing.

Some weird notes:
*I couldn't increment the z-index, then return it to its original z-index. For some reason this was not causing a rerender... I just had to continually increment the z-index.

*I couldn't apply the scroll event then remove either. I initially wanted to apply scroll event on open, on first scroll do the z-index thing to rerender, then remove the scroll event. Then reapply the scroll event if the drop down was opened again. This caused it to only work the first time even though the scroll event should have been applied each time the drop down was open. I just had to apply the scroll event and leave it (this was in a popup editor, so elements got destroyed later anyway).